How can an icalendar event that has changed date be marked as to expose this fact?
I've searched in both the spec:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545
And in Kanzaki:
https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/
But I did not manage to understand if there is a specific way to mark an event that has changed its dtstart (and then probably also its dtend/rrule/etc) since it was moved to another date.
For example, suppose an event in a park gets moved from June 1st to July 1st as the weather forecast was very bad on June 1st, how can I mark this in the exported ics file VEVENT block as to make sure everybody that has subscribed the calendar would notice this?
Thanks!

Via the "Change Management Component Properties", perhaps? https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.7 You got LAST-MODIFIED and SEQUENCE there, SEQUENCE should start at 0, and then get incremented with any significant change. You got to keep the same UID value, of course, for any clients to realize this is an event they already know about, and not a new one.

As CBroe said in the comment:
Via the "Change Management Component Properties", perhaps?
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.7
You got LAST-MODIFIED and SEQUENCE there, SEQUENCE should start at 0, and then get incremented with any significant change. You got to keep the same UID value, of course, for any clients to realize this is an event they already know about, and not a new one.
Thanks CBroe!
